# Remove duplicate from two List <Object>

Tags: java

Class School which extends to Students class

```
package sample.compareTwoObject;

import java.util.Objects;

public class SchoolObj extends Students
{
    private String name;
    private String school;



    public SchoolObj(String nameStr, String schoolStr,String StdName,String rollNo)
    {
        super(StdName ,rollNo);

        this.setName(nameStr);
        this.setSchool(schoolStr);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSchool()
    {
        return this.school;
    }

    public void setSchool(String school)
    {
        this.school = school;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.getName() + ' ' + this.getSchool();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        SchoolObj schoolObj = (SchoolObj) o;
        return name.equals(schoolObj.name) && school.equals(schoolObj.school);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, school);
    }
}
```

class student

```
package sample.compareTwoObject;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Students {
    private String name;
    private String rollNo;

    public Students(String name, String rollNo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(String rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Students students = (Students) o;
        return name.equals(students.name) && rollNo.equals(students.rollNo);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, rollNo);
    }
}
```

here I'm trying to merge two Lists removing duplicate data

```
package sample.compareTwoObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<SchoolObj> listOne = new ArrayList<SchoolObj>();
        // TODO: Add sample data to listOne.
        listOne.add(new SchoolObj("nameA", "schoolX","Ramesh","24"));
        listOne.add(new SchoolObj("nameC", "schoolZ","Aman","24"));

        List<SchoolObj> listTwo = new ArrayList<SchoolObj>();
        // TODO: Add sample data to listTwo.
        listTwo.add(new SchoolObj("nameA", "schoolX","kk","24"));
        listTwo.add(new SchoolObj("nameB", "schoolY","Raj","24"));

       

        // Print results from stream method.
        System.out.println("Results from stream concat method:");
        List<SchoolObj> resultsViaConcatStream = StreamTest.createConcatListViaStream(listOne, listTwo);
        for (SchoolObj obj : resultsViaConcatStream)
        {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }

    

    public static List<SchoolObj> createConcatListViaStream(List<SchoolObj> listOne, List<SchoolObj> listTwo)
    {
        List<SchoolObj> listOneList = null;
        if(!listOne.containsAll(listTwo)) {
            listOneList = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(),listTwo.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
           
        }
        return listOneList;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
Results from stream concat method:
Size: 3
nameA schoolX
nameC schoolZ
nameA schoolX
nameB schoolY
```

But I'm getting:

```
Results from stream concat method:
Size: 3
nameA schoolX
nameC schoolZ
nameB schoolY
```

Why is it ignoring `new SchoolObj("nameA", "schoolX","kk","24")`

Comment: Why are you expecting two lines with `nameA schoolX`, when you are using `distinct` to remove the duplicates? And why do you expect `Size: 3`, but four lines of output?

Comment: Your equals/hashcode does not take into account the fields of the superclass

Comment: I need my code to consider equals and hashcode of super class.. how can I make it possible...

Comment: **solution**  ```java  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        SchoolObj schoolObj = (SchoolObj) o;
        boolean res = false;
        if(o instanceof Students ) {
            Students studentObj = (Students) o;
            res = super.equals(studentObj);
        }
        return name.equals(schoolObj.name) && school.equals(schoolObj.school)&&res;
    } ``` replace equals of SchoolObj  with this equals

Answer (score 2):

Your `SchoolObj` only considers the fields `name` and `school` when comparing equal, so the `distinct` in your `createConcatListViaStream` will cut out duplicates where those two fields match.

If you wanted the code/rules from `Students` to also apply, you'd have to call `super.equals()` and use that value in your `equals` comparison or compare the additional fields explicitly.

Besides: it doesn't make a lot of sense, logically, for a `School` class to extend `Student`: A school is not a type of student, in any sane sense. A school might have a list of students or alternatively a student might be assigned to a given school, but they shouldn't extend from each other.

Answer (score 0):

its because of equals method of both Student and School
it compares only name and rollNo

```
// School
name.equals(schoolObj.name) && school.equals(schoolObj.school);
// Student
name.equals(students.name) && rollNo.equals(students.rollNo)
```

based on this comparison below records have same name and rollNo, so you have only one left in final result

```
listOne.add(new SchoolObj("nameA", "schoolX","Ramesh","24"));
listTwo.add(new SchoolObj("nameA", "schoolX","kk","24"));
```